# zsh config - to export or not to export?

Tags: shell, zsh

When setting variables in my `~/.zshrc` I can either use `export`

```
export PATH=/some/path
```

or not

```
PATH=/some/path
```

How do these differ and which should I use?

Comment: Environmental variables that are also used by non-interactive shells (say, a shell script you wrote) should go into `.zshenv`.

Comment: Is `~/.zshenv` sourced by login shells as well? Should `PATH` be defined there?

Comment: `PATH` is probably the best example of a variable that should be defined inside `~/.zshenv`, this file gets sourced by **any** zsh session (unless you use some option to turn that off). See `man zsh` for a review of which files get sourced and in which order.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want programs run from zsh to see the var, export it.
For path, you probably want to export.
Instead of `export PATH=/some/path` you probably want `export PATH="$PATH:/some/path"`, unless you intend to clear out the system preset path completely.

Comment: That's great, thanks. I'll use export as a general rule now then.

Comment: But how do the two differ? Especially in the case where it is not about `PATH`. What if I do `JAVA_HOME=...` versus `export JAVA_HOME=..`

Comment: “[you _**probably**_ want `export`](https://superuser.com/a/598823)” (emphasis mine) doesn’t actually the question of how they differ, and it only _probably_ answers whether OP should include `export`. More, the answer does give good advice about not erasing `PATH`, but that advice is not related to the question.

Answer (score 29):

Demure already answered your specific question. However, this is a `zsh` question and about `PATH`. So here is another point: besides the standard variable `$PATH`, there is also `$path`, which is an array. Here you see the difference (colons or not...):

```
$ print $PATH
/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
$ print $path
/bin /usr/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/X11R6/bin
```

Both variants are automatically kept in sync. So, what's the benefit of using an array?

- The latter you can declare via `typeset -U path` to "keep only the first occurrence of each duplicated value" (from `man zshbuiltins`). That means this keeps your path clean, even if you successively source your `~/.zshrc` (because you changed it or whatever) and do not clutter it up with the same values again and again.
- You can use `path+=(/new/path)` to add a new directory to your PATH. To remove an element you have to use some tricks, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3435355/2037712 or http://www.zsh.org/mla/users//2005/msg01132.html
- You can easily loop over the elements in the PATH via `for i ($path) { print $i # or do something else }`

Finally, here is an excerpt from my config:

```
typeset -U path
path=(/new/path1
      /new/path2
      $path)
export PATH
```

Comment: Thank you, that was actually a follow up question. I will look at managing my path using `path` rather than `PATH`.

Comment: Glad to hear as I already feared that I'm OT. Btw. another advantage I forgot: You can easily loop over the elements with `for i ($path) { print $i # or do something else }`.

Comment: If I add an entry to Zsh’s `path`, it’s not also added to `PATH`, is it?

Comment: @Lucas: "Both variants are automatically kept in sync."