# What is the right way to set the $PATH variable in .zshrc

Tags: shell, zsh

When I first installed Zsh (using Oh My Zsh), the `~/.zshrc` file had the following commented lines by default:

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

What is the author trying to say here? Bash was the default shell on macOS and Linux, so yes, I was coming from Bash. Were they trying to say that I should just uncomment the second line? Or were they saying that I should do some other setup that I should look for on the internet?

Anyone who is well versed is welcome to explain how should I configure the `$PATH` the right way when I first install Zsh on my MacBook with OS X 10.11 El Capitan.

Comment: Maybe [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/598924/195224) to another question might give you some further information on how to set your `PATH` variable effectively.

Answer (score 8):

There is nothing wrong in setting your path by uncommenting the second line. However, having that path enabled by default in oh-my-zsh will, at the very least, be annoying. Why? You could have already set up your own PATH and then this will break functionality you've explicitly set up.

The author is trying to say that bash environments do not have `$HOME/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` in their default `PATH`, however, both places are quite popular for packets(/usr/local/bin is where anything you install lives in UNIX systems like FreeBSD while $HOME/bin is usually for user installed packets that were installed without root privileges).

Lastly, you can set up your `PATH` the best way that fits your needs. A good way will be to start with examining what's currently in your `PATH` and adding any extra paths to it as you find fit

```
export PATH=/some/path:$PATH
```

Comment: I will be using `brew` for installing packages. There are some recommendations out there - on how to setup $PATH variable. Brew creates symlinks when it installs packages. If $PATH is not set right, it can create some headaches when using brew installed packages. What do you think is the best approach from that perspective?

Comment: Well, I've used `brew` with `zsh`(not `oh-my-zsh`) and I've had no problems apart from when using packages that already exist in the system(like python for instance). The best approach will be to do whatever `brew` documentation suggests. If you ever run into issues, you can always modify your `PATH` to resolve.

Comment: `PATH=/some/path:$PATH` seems to work identically to the [suggested](https://superuser.com/revisions/1297426/2#rev31a6b330-37b8-4990-8243-5196fdcaf2a1) `export PATH=/some/path:$PATH` and keeps `/some/path` in my `PATH` across sessions and terminal windows. In fact, after removing all instances of `export` in my `~/.zshrc` and rebooting, I can’t find any differences at all in functionality. (!) Is `export` actually ever necessary in Z Shell?

Comment: Uncommenting that line won't break your existing path since it has `:$PATH` at the end. I think the middle paragraph does explain why the zshrc author wrote that comment though. I always thought it was a bad translation or something hah.

Comment: @Lucas: `export` is definitely needed in general, though many individual occurrences might not be. `export` sets an internal flag on a shell variable that tells the shell to pass it as an environment variable to any programs it runs. Anything that's *already* an environment variable will already have that flag set, so you shouldn't need to add an extra `export` when updating it; that's why you found that `export PATH=...` doesn't do anything beyond what `PATH=...` does.

Answer (score 4):

[Oh My ZSH](https://ohmyz.sh/) encourages users (in the final section of `.zshrc` file) to put personal configurations like alias and themes into the directory set as the `$ZSH_CUSTOM`.

I think it is a good idea to keep all your configurations in this directory, including your path customization. That way you can easily include it to your backups, and restore when necessary.

1. `cd $ZSH_CUSTOM`
2. `nano my_paths.zsh`
3. Put your line into that file to add a new path to your `$PATH`:

```
# Add Flutter to path
export PATH=$PATH:~/dev/flutter/bin
```

4. Save and close the editor
5. Restart your shell, and confirm that your path is updated:

`$ echo $PATH`