# How to set the PATH variable with .zshrc

Tags: mac, zsh, environment-variables, path, macos-bigsur

I am trying to compile a program using Intel C and Fortran compilers (icc and ifort) on my Mac (Big Sur 11.2). Both icc and ifort executables are located in `/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.2.0/mac/bin`. My understanding is that I need to add this to my `PATH` variable using `.zshrc`.

So I create a blank document called `.zshrc` in my home directory and then add the following line:

```
export PATH=/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.2.0/mac/bin:$PATH
```

However, this does not seem to change anything. If I open a Terminal (zsh shell), and type `which icc`, it still cannot be found. And if I do `printenv`, I can see the PATH variable which is:

```
PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

How do I add `/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.2.0/mac/bin` to my PATH?

I've seen similar questions with answers on here such as [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1297418/what-is-the-right-way-to-set-the-path-variable-in-zshrc), but trying to follow their steps does not solve the problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Note: I have previously been able to edit the PATH variable using `.bash_profile` but I am now using zsh on Big Sur 11.2 on Mac OS x.

Comment: What is the value of `echo $SHELL` when you open your terminal?

Comment: `echo $SHELL` returns `/bin/zsh`

Comment: That's very strange indeed. Make sure the file is readable. Add something like `echo foobar` to that file, then restart your terminal. If you see the message `foobar` at the top of the terminal, then the file is being read properly

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I appended the new path to the PATH variable in .zshrc in my home directory. The key was to restart the Terminal app to make it work.