# What is the difference between zsh's $path and $PATH?

Tags: zsh

As I start to migrate from bash to zsh, I'm finding many differences. One of them is the following:

```
envy% echo $path
/usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /opt/X11/bin

envy% echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

Why do these mirror each other except for the spaces and colons and when you modify them? What's the understanding about zsh environment variables that I don't have here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$PATH` ist a scalar variable, whereas `$path` is an array.

Notice that in the first case the directories are delimited by colons inside the `$PATH` string itself; in the second case the array is automatically expanded and separated by spaces:

```
$ print $PATH
/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
$print $path
/bin /usr/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/X11R6/bin
```

Both variants are automatically kept in sync by *zsh*. So, what's the benefit of using a array?

- The latter you can declare via `typeset -U path` to "keep only the first occurrence of each duplicated value" (from `man zshbuiltins`). That means this keeps your path clean, even if you successively source your `~/.zshrc` (because you changed it or whatever) and do not clutter it up with the same values again and again.
- You can use `path+=(/new/path)` to add a new directory to your PATH. To remove an element you have to use some tricks, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3435355/2037712 or http://www.zsh.org/mla/users//2005/msg01132.html
- You can easily loop over the elements in the PATH via `for i ($path) { print $i # or do something else }`

Finally, here is an excerpt from my config with my attempt to keep my search path tidy:

```
typeset -U path
path=(/new/path1
      /new/path2
      $path)
export PATH
```

*Source: My own [answer](https://superuser.com/a/598924/195224) to another question.*

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you.